# Faction Error in OpenCV to make the online attendance system (Not able to fetch the data from database)

Tags: python, mysql, tkinter

**strong text :**
**This the error of my code I don't know how to fixe it please solve it. Here i am using Python 3.7**

```
File "c:\Users\ARAVIND SINGH\Desktop\Face Recogtion Attention System\face_recognition.py", line 105, in face_recog
    img=recogize(img,clf,faceCascade)
  File "c:\Users\ARAVIND SINGH\Desktop\Face Recogtion Attention System\face_recognition.py", line 94, in recogize
    coord=draw_boundray(img,faceCascade,1.1,10,(255,25,255),"Face",clf)
  File "c:\Users\ARAVIND SINGH\Desktop\Face Recogtion Attention System\face_recognition.py", line 69, in draw_boundray
    n="+".join(n)
TypeError: can only join an iterable
```

**strong text**

Here is my code :

```
from tkinter import* 
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import Image,ImageTk
from tkinter import messagebox
import mysql.connector
import sqlite3
import os
import cv2
import numpy as np
import tracestack


 
class Face_Reconition:
    def __init__(self,root):
        self.root=root
        self.root.geometry('1530x790-0+0')
        self.root.title("Face Recogintion System")

        
        title_label=Label(self.root,text="Face Recongition",font=('times new roman',35,"bold"),bg='white',fg="darkgreen")
        title_label.place(x=0,y=0,width=1530,height=48)

    # Fist image
        img_top=Image.open(r"img\face_detector1.jpg")
        img_top=img_top.resize((650,700),Image.ANTIALIAS)
        self.photoimg_left=ImageTk.PhotoImage(img_top)

        f_lbl=Label(self.root,image=self.photoimg_left)
        f_lbl.place(x=0,y=50,width=650,height=700)
    # Second Image

        img_bottom=Image.open(r"img\ww.jpg")
        img_bottom=img_bottom.resize((950,700),Image.ANTIALIAS)
        self.photoimg_bottom=ImageTk.PhotoImage(img_bottom)

        f_lbl=Label(self.root,image=self.photoimg_bottom)
        f_lbl.place(x=650,y=50,width=950,height=700)

    #Button

        b1=Button(f_lbl,text="Face Reconition",cursor='hand2',command=self.face_recog,font=('time new roman',18,'bold'),bg='darkgreen',fg='white')
        b1.place(x=370,y=620,width=200,height=40)


#=============Face Reconition ============== function======


    def face_recog(self):
        def draw_boundray(img,classifier,scalFactor,minNeighbors,color,text,clf):
            gray_image=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
            features=classifier.detectMultiScale(gray_image,scalFactor,minNeighbors)

            coord=[]

            for (x,y,w,h) in features:
                cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),3)
                id,predict=clf.predict(gray_image[y:y+h,x:x+w])

                confidence=int((100*(1-predict/300)))

                conn=mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",user="root",password="12345",database="face_recognizer")
                my_cursor=conn.cursor()


                my_cursor.execute("select Name from student where Student_id="+str(id))
                n=my_cursor.fetchone()
                n="+".join(n)

                my_cursor.execute("select Roll from student where Student_id="+str(id))
                r=my_cursor.fetchone()
                r="+".join(r)

                my_cursor.execute("select Dep from student where Student_id="+str(id))
                d=my_cursor.fetchone()
                d="+".join(d)



                if confidence>77:
                    cv2.putText(img,f"Roll:{r}",(x,y-55),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX,0.8,(255,255,255),3)
                    cv2.putText(img,f"Name:{n}",(x,y-30),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX,0.8,(255,255,255),3)
                    cv2.putText(img,f"Department:{d}",(x,y-5),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX,0.8,(255,255,255),3)

                else:
                    cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,0,255),3)
                    cv2.putText(img,"Unknon Face",(x,y-5),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX,0.8,(255,255,255),3)

                coord=[x,y,w,h]
            return coord
        
        def recogize(img,clf,faceCascade):
            coord=draw_boundray(img,faceCascade,1.1,10,(255,25,255),"Face",clf)
            return img
        
        faceCascade=cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
        clf=cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()
        clf.read("classifier.xml")

        video_cap=cv2.VideoCapture(0)

        while True:
            ret,img=video_cap.read()
            img=recogize(img,clf,faceCascade)
            cv2.imshow("Welcome to face Regonition ",img)

            if cv2.waitKey(1)==13:
                break

        video_cap.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        tracestack.pm()


if __name__=="__main__":
    root=Tk()
    obj=Face_Reconition(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Did you try to print out the result of `fetchone()` and see whether you have retrieved record from the database?  The error indicates that no record is found.